# From the God-Machine Chronicles, what do the different intensity stun guns do?

Tags: combat, weapons, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

What do the three intensities of this weapon do?
It's made clear that:
• = 1 intensity
•• = 2
••• = 3

But intensity is no further mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The World of Darkness (WW55000)](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/1124/) covers Stun (p167):

> **Stun:** some weapons pack such a wallop that if damage successes inflicted in a single attack equal or exceed the target's Size, he loses his next action.

[Mage: the Ascension Revised (WW4600)](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/199/) describes stun guns under Bashing Damage (p246):

> **Bashing Damage**
>   …This also includes energy or chemical attacks that are designed to render the victim unconscious, such as stun guns or knockout gas…

Based on these two rules I would say that stun guns do:

- bashing damage equal to intensity.
- stuns target for a number of turns equal to intensity (ignoring the damage >= size weapon rule).

The intent of a stun gun is to incapacitate a target, not severely wound them, but sending that many volts into a person is likely to cause some harm due to muscular convulsions.

Comment: Is the bashing damage equal to the intensity, or is all damage from a stun gun bashing damage?

Comment: @Jason_c_o I don't have the book in question so I can't answer that specifically, just offering my opinion based on experience with cWoD and how I would handle the system without clear rules.

Comment: I'm not sure how Ascension's rules have anything to do with [tag:nwod].

Comment: @okeefe It was a [wod] book in my PDF library that came up with a search result for stun guns, I'm not very familiar with [nwod] but it didn't seem like damage changed much between cWoD revised and [nwod].

Comment: This is probably the closest I feel to an nstar, and how I'd rule it but word of god (machine) would be more satisfying.

Comment: Damage changed significantly between nWoD:GMC and nWoD though. (I will try and poke the GMC rules book about this later today)

Comment: -1) After looking at the GMC-rules. Your answer iswrong. It is also wrong for preGMC nwod.

Comment: @Oxinabox always feels good to be -1'd. I answered the best I could with the materials I have, maybe you should prod the poster to update the answer instead?

Comment: You indeed did your best, I do not question that.
However your answer is still wrong.
See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186083/should-i-downvote-incorrect-answer-on-my-own-question
 Wrong answers should be -1'd to reduce there vote counts so that people do not think they are correct answers.
the Rep loss is minimal to you, you have gained 30 Rep (from 3 upvotes) and lost 4 rep from the 2 down votes.
I also I believe you were misguided to attempt to answer this with your lack of knowledge of, and materials for, the system. Speculation does not a fantastic answer make.

Answer (score 3):

The Rule in question: from Page 192, Blood and Smoke, or from Page 240 from God Machine Chronicles (and not in Demon).

> ### Stun Gun
>
> Die Bonus 0, Durability 2, Size 1, Structure 2,
> Availability •,  ••,  o r  •••
>
> #### Effect:
>
> A stun gun is designed to deliver an
> overwhelming  amount of electricity to an assailant in order to shut
> down her  muscles and send her to the ground. As a defensive item,
> this  gives the would-be victim time to run or get help. As an
> offensive  item, it leaves the victim ready for restraint or worse.
> These devices come in two varieties (hand-held and ranged) and  three
> intensities (1–3, corresponding to their Availabilities). The
> hand-held model has live leads on the edge of a handle and can  be
> used as many as fifty times on one battery charge. The ranged  model
> fires small wired darts up to fifteen feet away. While the  ranged
> model has similar battery life, it uses a compressed air  cartridge
> that requires replacement after each shot.  Use of a handheld stun gun
> requires a Dexterity + Weaponry  roll, penalized by the victim’s
> Defense. The ranged model uses  Dexterity + Firearms, also penalized
> by the victim’s Defense. On  a successful hit with either, the victim
> takes one point of lethal  damage. The successes subtract from the
> victim’s next dice pool.  With the ranged version, the darts remain in
> the victim’s body,  adding three successes automatically each turn.
> They can be  removed with a Strength + Stamina roll, with the initial
> successes  penalizing the action. With the hand-held version, the
> attacker  can attempt to maintain the shock, which takes a Strength +
> Weaponry, penalized by the greater of the opponent’s Strength  or
> Defense. Once the accumulated successes exceed the victim’s  Size, the
> victim collapses in neuro-muscular incapacitation. Once  the shock
> ends, this lasts for (10 – victim’s Stamina) in turns.

This looks like it was poorly ported across from the nWoD Armoury (or from Hunter perhaps).
Annoyingly it was not clarified in blood and smoke (like a few other mistakes were).

It, like the Armoury stun gun, does not interact with the Stun rules -- or the Stunned Tilt as it now is. I feel this was a missed opportunity, though the reason it doesn't just apply the stunned tilt is because that only lasts one turn. It also does not impose
some form of  neuro-muscular incapacitation tilt, again missed opportunity to make it use the new rules.

### Interpretation:

The stun gun is not a weapons (it is in the wrong section). It uses weapon-like rules, but it basically doesn't do damage to a person, it instead accumulates to its own side counter, a amount of successes needed to render them unable to act.

#### Hitting

1. Hit with `Dex + Firearms/Weaponry - Defense`. Call the number of successes `X`. Do 1 Lethal damage.
2. Target takes a `-X` penalty to next action (only).

#### Maintaining

After it has hit, then to start shocking them it must be maintained.

If ranged, then to remove pins target must succeed on `Strength + Stamina - X`.
Until they do that the connection is maintained -- No action  from the attacker required. (Unlike old rules, which required action on the part of the attacker to keep hitting the sock button)

If he hand-held, then each turn the attacker must succeed on a `Strength-Weaponry - higher of  targets Defense/Strength` to maintain connection.

#### While Maintained

1. At the start of the fight, Zero successes have been accumulated towards taking them out. 
   Call the number of successes accumulated towards taking them out `Y` 
   (or formally `Y(t)` with Y(0)=0)
2. For each turn while maintained (this does not include the turn it was hit on), 
   on the attackers turn: 3 successes are added to Y. 
   (ie at time `t` being now, `Y(t)=Y(t-1)+3`)
3. If `Y>targets size` then target is unable to act, and collapses -- suffering the knock-down tilt. 
   Once (if) it is no longer maintained then the target will be able to act after a further `10-Stamina` turns.

### By RAW:

Changing the Intensity does nothing. You are correct it is never mentioned again.

### My suggested Ruling

I would suggest that the Intensity controls how many successes are added to Y each turn of maintaining -- Point 2 under maintaining.

Ie a Intensity 3 Stun Gun accumulates 3 successes onto Y per turn of maintaining (same as by RAW).
Intensity 1 only accumulates 1 to Y per turn, and Intensity 2, accumulates 2.

This makes sense, since once someone is rendered unable to act by the stun gun, they are out of the fight. At `10-Stamina` rounds (which assumes the stunning stops immediately, which for Ranged there is no reason to), even someone with Stamina 5 is unlikely to recover before the fight is over. At which point, with all other threats neutralised, the attacker can cut his throat, or beat him with a brick till he is actually unconscious, or tie him up or what ever.

So you don't really want a tool that can do that to *anyone* in 3 rounds (1 hit, 2 maintained)  that to be a Availability 1, item.
Though that is roughly what is was in nWoD: Armoury (but as described even ranged took action to maintain).
So scaling the time it takes with the cost makes sense.

#### If needs more:

I would consider also ruling that while it is maintained takes takes a penalty to all actions equal to its Intensity. Cos being shocked is not fun.

### See also:

- [Discussion on the Onyx Path Forum](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/63543-gmc-stun-gun-intensity) (I disagree with the resolution)
- [Question on the nWoD (preGMC) rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/42132/i-have-an-electrified-baton-what-damage-does-it-do/) (about stun batons)